# How to read parquet file with a condition using pyarrow in Python

Tags: python, filter, conditional-statements, parquet, pyarrow

I have created a parquet file with three columns (id, author, title) from database and want to read the parquet file with a condition (title='Learn Python').
Below mentioned is the python code which I am using for this POC.

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

def write_to_parquet(df, out_path, compression='SNAPPY'):
arrow_table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
if compression == 'UNCOMPRESSED':
    compression = None
pq.write_table(arrow_table, out_path, use_dictionary=False,
               compression=compression)

def read_pyarrow(path, nthreads=1):
return pq.read_table(path, nthreads=nthreads).to_pandas()


path = './test.parquet'
sql = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Book] (NOLOCK)"

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={SQL 
Server};Server=.;Database=APP_BBG_RECN;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
df = pd.io.sql.read_sql(sql, conn)

write_to_parquet(df, path)

df1 = read_pyarrow(path)
```

How can I put a condition (title='Learn Python') in read_pyarrow method?

Answer (score 5):

Filters are now available read_table

```py
table = pq.read_table(
        df, filters=[("title", "in", {'Learn Python'}), 
                     ("year", ">=", 1950)]
    )
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not yet supported. We intend to develop this functionality in the future. I recommend doing the filtering with pandas after the conversion from Arrow table.

Comment: Any update? What is the current state, on 2018-07-22?

Comment: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.ParquetDataset.html See filter section. Haven't tried it myself.