# Pandas and FastParquet read a single partition

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow, fastparquet

I have a miserably long running job to read in a dataset that has a natural, logical partition on US State. I have saved it as a partitioned parquet dataset from pandas using fastparquet (using pd.write_parquet).

I want my buddy to be able to read in just a single partition (state) from the parquet folder that's created. read_parquet doesn't have a filter ability. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try using either `dask` or `parquet` reader.  Filtering via `pandas` has worked for me.

[How to read parquet file with a condition using pyarrow in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48714803/how-to-read-parquet-file-with-a-condition-using-pyarrow-in-python)

```py
RUN pip install pyarrow
RUN pip install "dask[complete]"

import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

path = ""
dask_df = dd.read_parquet(path, columns=["col1", "col2"], engine="pyarrow")

dask_filter_df = dask_df[dask_df.col1 == "filter here"]

path = ""
parquet_pandas_df = pq.ParquetDataset(path).read_pandas().to_pandas()

pandas_filter_df = parquet_pandas_df[parquet_pandas_df.col1 == "filter here"]
```